# Expected number of widgets(Markov chain)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that a machine making widgets operate at $5$ levels of efficiency ($1$ being the
best, $5$ being completely broken). Suppose that the efficiency of the machine from one day
to the next evolves according to a Markov chain with the following transition matrix.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.9 & 0.05   &0.03  &0.02  & 0 \\ 
 0&0.9  &0.05  &0.03  &0.02 \\ 
 0&0  &0.8  &0.1  &0.1 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0.6  &0.4 \\ 
 0& 0 &0  &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Suppose also that the number of widgets the machine produces in a given day depends on the efficiency level of the machine according to the following table:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Efficiency Level} & \text{Widgets Produced}\\\hline
1 & 1000\\
2 & 900\\
3 & 700\\
4 & 500
\end{array}

If a brand new machine is currently operating at efficiency level $1$, what is the expected
number of widgets it will be able to produce before the machine completely breaks (efficiency
level 5).

What I am doing : Level $5$ is the absorbing state. So, my Q matrix is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.9 & 0.05   &0.03  &0.02  \\ 
 0&0.9  &0.05  &0.03  \\ 
 0&0  &0.8  &0.1 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0.6  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I calculate my R matrix which is: $(I_{4} - Q)$ inverse where I is the identity matrix and it gives me:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 5   &2.75  &1.5625  \\ 
 0& 10 &2.5  & 1.375  \\ 
 0&0  &5  &1.25 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &2.5  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

which means that it takes 10 days for the machine to leave level 1 and 5 for level 2 and so on. So, will my final answer be: 17206.25 ( 10*1000 + 5*900 + 2.75*700 + 500*1.5625) or should it be 10*1000 + 10*900 + 5*700 + 500*2.5 = 23250? I am confused about this :(

Comment: with $\mathbf v := \left[\begin{matrix}1000\\900\\700\\500\end{matrix}\right]$  then $\mathbf e_1^T (I_4-Q)^{-1}\mathbf v$ will do it... do you know any renewal theory?  There's a nice way to get this answer by slightly altering the markov chain to be recurrent and applying a little renewal theory--- it also can serve as a very useful check when you are confused about the absorbing state formulation.  (I'll write this up if you know some renewal theory... but it won't make sense if you aren't famiiar)

Comment: We just started Markov chains and haven't done any renewal theory.

Comment: so, 17206.25000 should be the final answer?

Comment: yes.  you may consider applying your method to $\mathbf v' := \left[\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$.  It will give you $10$ which is what you'd anticipate since there is a geometric distribution associated with leaving state 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this $\texttt R$ code to simulate the Markov chain:

```
rm(list=ls())

N <- 10000

next_state <- function(i) {
  u <- runif(1)
  if(i==1) {
    if(u < 0.9)
      return(1)
    else if(u < 0.95)
      return(2)
    else if(u < 0.98)
      return(3)
    else
      return(4)
  }
  else if(i==2) {
    if(u<0.9)
      return(2)
    else if(u<0.95)
      return(3)
    else if(u<0.98)
      return(4)
    else
      return(5)
  }
  else if(i==3) {
    if(u<0.8)
      return(3)
    else if(u<0.9)
      return(4)
    else
      return(5)
  }
  else if(i==4) {
    if(u<0.6)
      return(4)
    else
      return(5)
  }
  else
    return(5)
}

widgets <- function(i) {
  if(i==1)
    return(1000)
  else if(i==2)
    return(900)
  else if(i==3)
    return(700)
  else if(i==4)
    return(500)
  else
    return(0)
}

W <- rep(0, N)

for(i in 1:N) {
  state <- 1
  while(state<5) {
    W[i] <- W[i] + widgets(state)
    state <- next_state(state)
  }
}

print(mean(W))
```

It's giving an output of $\sim17200$-$17300$, for what that's worth.

Comment: That's cool, but what I am getting by doing the method that I explained above is 17206.25, which is inside this range. So, I am assuming that this is correct.